# Facebook like button's iframe not expanded after ajax request

Tags: ajax, facebook, wordpress, facebook-like

I'm adding a facebook share button to each post on a Wordpress (Using Facebook Share Button New plugin), it works ok for each post/page except when i'm loading them trough ajax, the result it's a normal Facebook like button but the popup (to write a comment) appears inside the button it is not expanded.

To check go to: http://iwanttobeher.com/ and then click on any face at the bottom of the page, then test the like button and you'll see what happens.

I don't know what to do, i tried to `FB.XFBML.parse()` after loading the content but the result is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to fix it by changing the implementation to **HTML5** instead Iframe or XFBML using Facebook's tool to generate like buttons: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

Answer (score 2):

Switching to HTML5 didn't help in our case. What did was to remove the `FB` object just prior to new content being inserted into the page via Ajax:

```
delete FB;
wrapper.html(response.data);
```

We reload full pages via Ajax and so new page content recreates the FB object and re-initializes XFBML anyway. Not sure if this workaround would work if we reloaded only parts of the page though.

The original answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17760601/1712145).